# The number of days that elapse between the beginning of the calendar year and the moment a high-risk driver is involved in an accident ...

Tags: statistics

The number of days that elapse between the beginning of the calendar year and the moment a high-risk driver is involved in an accident is exponentially distributed. An insurance company expects that $30$% of high-risk drivers will be involved in an accident during the first $50$ days of a calendar year. What portion of high-risk drivers is expected to be involved in an accident during the first $90$ days of a calendar year?

I have the CDF:
$$1 - e^{qx} \implies 1 - e^{-50q} \implies q = \frac {\ln(0.7)}{50}$$
Then for the $1$st $90$ days I used
$$ 1 - e^{-90q} \implies 1 - e^{\ln(0.7)^\frac{9}{5}}$$
then
$$1 - {0.7^\frac{9}{5}}=0.47$$

My answer seems a little off but I am not sure where. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You seem to have a few typos in the calculations. The following is the correct version. 

$$1-e^{50q} = 0.3 \Rightarrow e^{-50q} = 0.7 \Rightarrow -50q = \ln(0.7) \Rightarrow q = -\ln(0.7)/50.$$

Then, 

$$1-e^{-90q} = 1-e^{9/5 \ln(0.7)} = 1 - 0.7^{1.8} \approx 0.474.$$

Comment: @RishiSonthalia Thank you, is the answer I provided still correct?

Comment: Ya the method looks correct